# login system not finding username on plain text database

Tags: python, file-handling

This is my code:

```
name = input("What is your full name?")
age = input("How old are you?")
username = name[0:3] + age
password = input("What is your desired password?")
with open(name+'.txt', 'w') as details:
    details.write("Name: "+name)
    details.write("\nAge: "+age)
    details.write("\nUsername: "+username)
    details.write("\nPassword: "+password)
    print("Your details are saved in", name+'.txt')
details.close()
login = []
login = True
while login == True:
    login_name = input("What is your name?")
    login_age = input("How old are you?")
    username_attempt = input("Please enter your username:\n")
    password_attempt = input("Please enter your password:\n")
    username_finder = open(login_name+'.txt', 'r')
    for line in username_finder:
        if line == "\nUsername: "+login_name[0:3]+login_age:
            username = line
       #if line == 'Password: '+I DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE

        else:
            print("Sorry, this username does not exist")
```

Now from these you can see that I'm trying to fetch the username from the text file and compare it to the `username` inputted, but when I run it, it says that the term `username` is not defined.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Avoid posting your code in screenshots. You should put it inside codeblocks so people can copy-paste it so they're able to replicate.

Comment: @oScarDiAnno I am not sure how to do so as I'm new to SO, if you could teach me how that would be helpful

Comment: typo. `\m` in condition

Comment: I changed it to\n but it still didn't work @Van Peer

Comment: @AbdurahmanHijazi don't use `\n` as well, `line` is already stripped of `\n` I think

Comment: @Van Peer I have tested everything, with and without but it remains to not work. I then commented the line so that it ignores it and wrote print(line) so that it prints every line, but it skipped to my next line of code

Comment: You have to paste your code in your question's body, then put 4 spaces at the start of every line, and it'll put the code automatically inside a codeblock

Comment: @oScarDiAnno  ok ill edit my question

Comment: I have edited my code, you should be able to see my code now if I'm not mistaken @oScarDiAnno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous thing wrong with your code, as well as several places that things could be done more clearly (or succinctly). Here's a reworked version of it that does what you want, I believe:

```
import os

print("Register with login system.")
name = input("What is your full name? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")
password = input("What is your desired password? ")
username = name[0:3] + age
filename = username + ".txt"

with open(filename, "w") as details:
    details.write("Name: {}\n".format(name))
    details.write("Age: {}\n".format(age))
    details.write("Username: {}\n".format(username))
    details.write("Password: {}\n".format(password))

print("Your username is", username)
#print("Your details were saved in", filename)  # Don't need to show this.

login = []
login = True
print("\nPlease log in.")
while login == True:
    login_username = input("What is your username? ")
    filename = login_username + ".txt"
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("Sorry, that's not a valid username, try again.")
    else:
        login_password = input("What is your password? ")
        with open(filename, "r") as user_file:
            for line in user_file:
                line = line.strip()  # Removed newline at end.
                if line.startswith("Password:"):
                    password = line.split(" ")[1]
                    print("password read from file: ", repr(password))
                    break
        if password == login_password:
            login = False
        else:
            print("Sorry, that's the wrong password, starting over.")

print("You are now logged in.")
```

Answer (score 0):

- Better concatenate the username with the file extension, before your `with open`.
- When using `with open`, you don't need to close the file descriptor.
- Make the user interaction simpler (objective messages).
- Watch out for the [variable scope](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/)!
- Your `ifs` could be simpler (and your application better), if you are willing to use a DBMS

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

name = input("Full Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
username = name[0:3] + age   # VARIABLE SCOPE
password = input("Desired Password: ")
filename = name + ".txt"

with open(filename, 'w') as details:
    details.write("Name: "+name)
    details.write("\nAge: "+age)
    details.write("\nUsername: "+username)
    details.write("\nPassword: "+password)
    print("Details saved in: ", filename)
```

---

Besides this, do you really think that it's a good a idea to keep a database of users and their credentials on a plain text file in this format? I believe that you should take a look on some topics like DBMS (MySQL, MongoDB, SQLite, etc.).

[MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) is a persistent "key-value store" database.

You can obtain data as JSON format, serialize, search for specific keys, etc.:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "Username":"Protoman",
      "Password":"dr.w1ll7"
   },
   "2":{  
      "Username":"Megaman",
      "Password":"d0g.Rus4"
   }
}
```

If you don't want to rely on a DBMS with a process/daemon to manage, having a database in plain text, you can have a try on [SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/).

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue

```
for line in username_finder:
    if line.startswith('Username: '):
        if line.strip() == "Username: "+login_name[0:3]+login_age:
            username = line
            login = False
        else:
            print("Sorry, this username does not exist")
```

And, do take care of other issues mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this out
`sample.py`

```
name = raw_input("Full name:: ")
age = raw_input("age:: ")
un = name[0:3]+age
passd = raw_input("pass:: ")
with open(name+'.txt','w') as details:
    details.write("name: {}".format(name))
    details.write("\nage: {}".format(age))
    details.write("\nusername: {}".format(un))
    details.write("\npassword: {}".format(passd))
print("Yours details are saved in file {}.txt".format(name))
```

`fetch.py`. I have hardcoded the file path. You can loop and read.

```
FILE_PATH = '/Users/kgowda/Desktop/my_work/play/agentX.txt'
USERNAME = ''
with open(FILE_PATH, 'r') as users:
    for line in users:
        if line.startswith("name"):
            USERNAME = line.split(":")[1]
if USERNAME is '':
    print("User not found")
else:
    print("User found")
```

Run and output is

```
[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ python sample.py 
Full name:: agentX 
age:: 30
pass:: hulkisstrong
Yours details are saved in file agentX.txt

[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ cat agentX.txt 
name: agentX
age: 30
username: age30
password: hulkisstrong

[mac] kgowda@blr-mp6xx:~/Desktop/my_work/play$ python fetch.py 
User found
```